# Taking alternative strings from group of strings in php

Tags: php

I want to take alternative strings from group of strings in php . How can I Do that.. any idea..??

```
$string = array('item1','item2','item3','item4');
```

I want alternative strings from above strings . almost having 100 items

I expect the output as

```
$val = item2,item4,item6,item8... item100
```

Comment: Maybe a for loop with a step of 2 ? :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop should do this for you

```
$val1 = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($string); $i=$i+2){
    $val1 .= $string[$i] . ',';
}
rtrim($val1, ','); // remove last `,`
echo $val1;
```